# Slow face detection Firebase MLKit

Tags: swift, camera, firebase-mlkit

Started playing around with MLKit face detectors with the front-facing camera, but it's really slow on processing faces

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

    print("Picture at ", Date())


    let visionImage = VisionImage(buffer: sampleBuffer)
    visionImage.metadata = metadata


    faceDetector?.detect(in: visionImage) { (faces, error) in
        guard error == nil, let faces = faces, !faces.isEmpty else {
            // Error. You should also check the console for error messages.
            let errorString = error?.localizedDescription
            print("Face detection failed with error: \(errorString)")
            return
        }

  }
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Thanks for reporting. ML Kit engs will take a look.

Comment: I'm voting to close this post as off-topic because it is a bug report and not really a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things you can try to speed up the detection:

1. Build your app in the release mode (optimized), as opposed to the debug mode.
2. When creating your faceDetector, please make sure to use a VisionFaceDetectorOptions and set its isTrackingEnabled to true.
3. When setting up your AVCaptureVideoDataOutput, please add the following key-value pair to its videoSettings:

key: kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey

value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA

Comment: Another thing to try is: set your AVCaptureSession's sessionPreset to AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium.

Comment: Thanks! Turning on face tracking significantly improved performance for me!

Comment: is there any solution for the same problem in face detection vision API in google ML kit?

Comment: @HimanshuMalik .. Hi I have the same problem with you, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

In My Case I was not following the proper Guidelines which are:
If you want to use face detection in a real-time application, follow these guidelines to achieve the best framerates:

Configure the face detector to use either face contour detection or classification and landmark detection, but not both:

### You shoud do for better frame rates

1. Contour detection
2. Landmark detection
3. Classification
4. Landmark detection and classification

### You shouldn't use these

Contour detection and landmark detection

Contour detection and classification

Contour detection, landmark detection, and classification

Find all the guidelines here:
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/android