# How to speed up image detecting using firebase_ml_vision of flutter package

Tags: flutter, dart, face-detection, firebase-mlkit

I am using firebase_ml_vision to detect face in my apps... but it always takes too long to get the result of processing image when I am using camera.. it much faster when I am using image from gallery.. here is the part of the code

```
final image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(imageFile);
        final faceDetector = FirebaseVision.instance.faceDetector(
            FaceDetectorOptions(
                mode: FaceDetectorMode.fast,
                enableLandmarks: false,
                enableClassification: false,
                enableContours: false,
                enableTracking: true));
        List<Face> faces = await faceDetector.processImage(image);
```

is there a way to speed up `List<Face> faces = await faceDetector.processImage(image);` when I am using camera? I have read this one ([Slow face detection Firebase MLKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441947/slow-face-detection-firebase-mlkit)) and trying to do the same to firebase_ml_vision package but still can not speed it up